# Choose email account before sending mail?

Tags: ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating a application with mail sending functionality. I am sending mail using MFMailComposeViewController. What I want to do is if there are multiple Mail accounts configured on user device then before sending mail it should ask for the sender email account. That from which user wants to send mail.

Is there any way to do this or this is provided by default. I am working on simulator so can't test right now.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set multiple accounts in your mail app. If you have multiple accounts there than while presenting MFMailComposer View there in `from` field it will allow you to choose your mail account from which you want to send mail. Its a default behaviour of Mail Composer.

Hope this helps :)